# Grails formRemote update

Tags: javascript, forms, grails

I want to use the grails formRemote to update only a part of my page. Only a specific div element. When the form is submitted the whole page refreshes with the not found page erro

What could be the problem?
resultset -> div i want to update

```
<g:formRemote method="post" update="resultset" name="formRemote" url="[ controller: 'Historie', action:'index' ]" >
//some input fields
 <g:actionSubmit value="Submit"/>
 </g:formRemote>

<div id="resultset">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the submit button to: `<g:submitToRemote update="resultset" action="show"/>` solved the problem!